# How to set the mouse acceleration in Debian-XFCE when attempts to do so are ignored?

Tags: debian, mouse, touchpad

Debian 9.6, on a Thinkpad W530.
Input device: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

It is not hard to find examples for how to do this, but what should I do when all the listed techniques are ignored or fail?

First I simply tried using the built-in GUI mouse settings system for the window manager (XFCE). I can set it to anything I want, but there is no difference at all.

Then I started looking and I tried e.g. this guide:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration

If I do:

> xset m {values}

This is simply ignored.

If I do:

> xinput --set-prop 'mouse brand' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2

I get an error that the property does not exist.

Indeed, my device doesn't seem to have this property, when I look over xinput list's output.

The hardware itself is working fine. I've had it working with arbitrary acceleration in Gentoo before, and in Windows. Same machine.

Comment: you can try to ask here : https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Comment: You need to be using the evdev driver. Your distro probably switched to libinput.